# Multiple conditionals to create variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with three columns representing three repeat measurements:

```
IDPupil    1       2       3
1        150.5   151.0   150.6    
2        156.3   156.5            
3        145.7   146.0            
4        151.4   151.6            
5        150.0   149.5   150.4
```

I would like to create a new variable by calculating the row mean (or median) of the three measurements based on the following:

a) If the difference between col 1 and col 2 >0.4 and there is a value in col 3 calculate the row median.
b) If the difference between col 1 and col 2 >0.4 and there is no value in col 3 print "NULL"
c) In all other cases (i.e. diff between col 1 and 2 is <0.4) calculate the row mean.

I have tried the following:

```
Hdiff= hwdata$Height1 - hwdata$Height2
 Hdiff2 = abs(Hdiff)
 Hdiff2

MeanH = if(Hdiff2 > 0.4 && hwdata$Height3 > 0) {
rowMedians(hwdata[, c("Height1", "Height2", "Height3")], na.rm = TRUE)

} else if(Hdiff2 > 0.4 & hwdata$Height3 == 0)
MeanH = "NULL"

}else rowMeans (hwdata [, c("Height1", "Height2", "Height3")], na.rm = TRUE)
{
```

I get errors:

```
'Error: could not find function "rowMedians"'
```

and

```
'Error: unexpected '}' in "}"'
```

R experience = 1 week. Is there a more parsimonious way of doing this?

Comment: You can use `ifelse` and `apply`;you need to provide the sample data.

Comment: Okay sample data provided.

Comment: The `}` error is because you closed your second `if` with a bracket but didn't open it with one.

Comment: The `rowMedians` error is because there is no such function.

Answer (score 1):

With the data you provided, this works:

```
dt<-read.table(text="IDPupil    1       2       3
1        150.5   151.0   150.6    
2        156.3   156.5   NA         
3        145.7   146.0   NA         
4        151.4   151.6   NA         
5        150.0   149.5   150.4",h=T)
> ifelse(abs(dt$X1-dt$X2)<0.4,rowMeans(dt[,-1],na.rm=T),apply(dt[,-1],1,median))
[1] 150.60 156.40 145.85 151.50 150.00
```

If your colum names are `Height1` etc. then you need to change `X1` to `Height1` etc.